# I need to store around 600 line of data from txt file into link list

Tags: python

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data='', next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

head = None
with open('All Equipment.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        head = node(line.strip(), head)


current = head
while current is not None:
    print(current.data)
    current = current.next
```

Here is the code. The problem is when I print, it will print in reverse which is start from the last line of text file until the first line. I worried maybe it will cause a problem when I want to try to add and delete the node by using this linked list.  I just learning python and I appreciate any extra knowledge.

Comment: Please click on "edit" button and fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

You can define an `append` method for the linked list that adds elements at the end like below:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append(self, data=''):
        new_node = Node(data)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            return

        self.tail.next = new_node
        self.tail = new_node


linked_list = LinkedList()

with open('All Equipment.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        linked_list.append(line.strip())

current = linked_list.head
while current is not None:
    print(current.data)
    current = current.next
```